# Having trouble to understand the output in a Jupyter notebook ("Learning Cython")

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, jupyter-notebook

In the O'Reilly video tutorial "Learning Cython" in chapter 5, there's a notebook called `strings.ipynb`.

First cell loads the Cython extension:

```
%load_ext cython
```

Followed by this Cython cell:

```
%%cython
# cython: language_level=3

def f(char* text):
    print(text)
```

Then the following cell is used to demonstrate that a (Unicode) string cannot be used as `char*` argument:

```
f('It is I, Arthur, son of Uther Pendragon')
```

The outcome here is a `TypeError` exception.

All of the above is what I'd expect from the author's remarks in the voice-over. However, the outcome of the next cell:

```
f(b'It is I, Arthur, son of Uther Pendragon')
```

was this:

```
b'It is I, Arthur, son of Uther Pendragon'
```

and that stumped me.

Having used a plain `print` in the function `f`, why does the output appear as if it was run through `repr` first, when inside the Cython code above it clearly was *not* run through `repr`?

The author doesn't even mention this somewhat (at least to me) unexpected result in the voice-over.

What gives? Why does the output look like it was first passed through `repr`? Are byte strings in Python 3 not "printable" (i.e. without `str` method) and therefore fall back to `repr`?

PS: I have to admit I'm coming from Python 2.x and haven't had too much exposure to Python 3.x, so perhaps the difference is therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it was. In Python 3, `bytes_str` uses [`bytes_repr` internally](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/bytesobject.c#L1370):

```
static PyObject *
bytes_str(PyObject *op)
{
    if (Py_BytesWarningFlag) {
        if (PyErr_WarnEx(PyExc_BytesWarning,
                         "str() on a bytes instance", 1))
            return NULL;
    }
    return bytes_repr(op);  // call repr on it
}
```

As such, `print` will, in essence, call `repr(bytes_instance)`.

Comment: Thanks. That explains it. The reference to the respective C code is a really nice touch!